# Mathematica Package for Bayesian Networks

Tags: graphs-and-networks, probability-or-statistics, modeling

Are there any packages that allow the simulation of Bayesian Networks with Mathematica? I found what seemed to be a promising package (Dynamics) on a Brown University URL,

http://www.cs.brown.edu/research/ai/dynamics/tutorial/Mathematica/ReadMe

with an example notebook here

http://www.cs.brown.edu/research/ai/dynamics/tutorial/Documents/GraphicalModels.html

but unfortunately it seems that it is not included on their public FTP server.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can't you contact someone and ask if they'd share the package ? You have the info.

Comment: Isn't this duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17138/probalistic-graphical-models-bayesian-networks

Comment: Flagged the [other one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17138/probalistic-graphical-models-bayesian-networks) as a duplicate of this.

Comment: @s.s.o I deleted the old one which I migrated from Meta.

Comment: Thanks for deleting the older question. I will send an email and find out.

Comment: Fyi, keep in mind the distinction between graphs and hypergraphs. A fundamental law of probability is the distinction between pairwise versus mutual dependence. Graphs can only model pairwise dependence.

Comment: Perhaps one could try to access the Bayesian network package in R from Mma using version 9 of the latter.  RLink looks pretty [awkward to use as compared to RPy2](http://blog.harald.schil.ly/2012/11/mathematica-9s-r-integration-vs-rpy2.html) thus far but perhaps that will change in the future.

Answer (score 5):

You can check the book Bayesian Logical Data Analysis for the Physical Sciences there is also Mathematica notebooks for v7 and v8 under Other Files section.

Comment: That's a great book.

Comment: Unfortunately there's nothing on Bayesian networks in this book.

Answer (score 4):

If you go up two levels in the url's hierarchy, you can find a copy of the bayesian network library.

Graphical models
http://cs.brown.edu/research/ai/dynamics/tutorial/Documents/GraphicalModels.html

tutorials including notebooks for most of the topics.
http://cs.brown.edu/research/ai/dynamics/tutorial/home.html