# Belief Network, Bayesian network

Tags: graphs-and-networks, probability-or-statistics

There is already a question about simulating Bayesian networks with Mathematica ([Mathematica Package for Bayesian Networks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17133/mathematica-package-for-bayesian-networks)). However, are there any packages or approaches which help in computing the probabilities (i.e. evaluating the graph) given a network?

Comment: For discrete BN and exact inference you may use [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128945/764) as a guideline.